# use Guava CharMatcher as a static fields in a class . Is CharMatcher thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, guava

I need to replace some characters in a string:
Each DOT to Underscore.

Simply do: `myString.replace(".","_");`
which works.

However, I want to use `CharMatcher` from Guava, which supposed to have better performance.

```
CharMatcher dotCharMatcher = CharMatcher.anyOf(".");
dotCharMatcher.replaceFrom(myString, "_");
```

It runs on a sever with many threads.

Can I make `dotCharMatcher` a static field in the class that uses it, or should I create one in each request? (is it thread safe?)

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, by [inspection of `CharMatcher.java`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/fa95e381e665d8ee9639543b99ed38020c8de5ef/guava/src/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.java), the instance returned from `anyOf` is thread-safe.

However, the [Guava's string utilities, explained](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained)  documentation specifically says that `Joiner` and `Splitter` are thread-safe but doesn't make the same claim for `CharMatcher`.

Comment: [Javadoc also mentions](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/fa95e381e665d8ee9639543b99ed38020c8de5ef/guava/src/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.java#L34) that _"Implementations are strongly encouraged to be side-effect-free and immutable."_

Comment: And the static `CharMatcher` constants must be thread-safe, and so anything used in their construction must be too.